# Diffing the bits of an integer

Tags: c#, integer, bit-manipulation

I have a 32 bit integer which I fill with data by mapping the individual bits to various types of data.

For instance one section is used for oxygen level. It's a value from 0 to 128, so I use 7 bits for that.

Another section is used for the rotation of the object. Rotation is always either 0, 90, 180 or 270 degrees around the three axis x, y and z. Each angle is indexed with the values 0, 1, 2 and 3, so I only need 6 bits. Rotation is stored as 010101 for a rotation of 90 deg around x, y and z, or 100000 for a rotation of 180 deg around x.

Some of the sections are stored as integer values, like with oxygen level, but cast to enums when I need to use them.

Each of the sections are laid out next to each other in the data integer, filling the bits from right to left.

```
Type :    ... | Oxygen  | Rotation |
          --------------------------
Bits:     ... | 0000000 | 000000   |
          --------------------------
Position: ... | 19-25   | 26-31    |
          --------------------------
```

## The problem

I would like to compare two integers and see what's changed.

When the oxygen level of one int is 16, and the other is 20, the difference is an increase of 4 units. When one rotation is 0 on all axis, and an other is 90 around x, the difference is a rotation around x of 90 deg.

I have extension methods on the data object that allows me to get the oxygen level as an int value, and the rotation as a quaternion. When using these on the delta data object, I would like to get the value 4 for oxygen level, and a quaternion for the rotation 90 deg around x.

## Question

What's the most efficient way to get the difference in value of two integers?

## Possible approaches

I've thought about a couple of different ways to approach this.

### Integer comparing

Since the data is an integer, I tried to simply subtract one from the other. I started with an int with a value of 0 and set the bits for oxygen level to 16. I created a new int, set its oxygen level to 20, and subtracted the first from the last, and the oxygen level of the delta was 4. But as I added rotation and other data to the integers, the result after the subtraction changed the resulting oxygen level and rotation.

I need to verify that all my extension methods are working as intended. All unit tests succeeds, but the tests might not be good enough.

### Bitwise comparing

Another approach was to compare each bit separately throughout the entire integer, using the various bitwise operators. I used an int with the rotation bits set to 90 deg around x (bits 01). Another int had the x rotation set to 180 deg (bits 10). The delta value I was looking for is 90 deg (bits 01), but I couldn't find any suitable operators to produce that result.

This test led me to believe that I can't compare bits separately. In the case of the rotation indexes, I need to look at a pair of bits as a single value.

### BitArray

I read the documentation for .net's BitArray, but couldn't immediately see using that would make any difference.

### Compare each section

Comparing each bit section would produce the result I'm looking for. The rotation bits would be converted to a quaternion before calculating the difference, and then converted back to bits before setting them in the data integer.

This is the approach I was hoping to find an alternative to. I didn't want the comparer to know the structure of the data, and I was hoping to find a more efficient solution.

*Edit*

I see now, after reading the comments and doing more testing, that it would be more beneficial for my case to get only the new value of a bit section, and not how much they changed. Any section that remains unchanged should be zeroed out. As far as I can see, my only option is to compare the data sectionwise.

*Edit again*

I'm not sure which answer to pick as the correct one. I don't think my question was specific enough, and am sorry for that.

The method given by @harold works when comparing bit by bit, and is independent of the data structure.

The answer by @Pikoh compares section by section, and can be made dynamic so that the method won't need to know about the data structure.

Comment: What is "the difference", if subtraction isn't what you want? Detecting that two integers *are* different is trivial. If you want "the" difference, you'll need to define this operation first. Simply stating how you're laying out your data isn't enough. (And it sounds like you want multiple "differences" for different sections.)

Comment: "the difference" isn't enough to tell us what you want here. You need to tell us the expected output from such a difference comparison. This is also evident in this part of your question: "didn't produce the result I was looking for". You have not told us what you're looking for, so we cannot help you.

Comment: Sounds to me like the second option is the most straightforward. Could you post the code that you've tried for that?

Comment: this is fairly bad practice, you shouldn't combine disparate data in the same variable, if there is some reason why you have this from your source then you should split them into separate variables in code before trying to perform operations on it, then you can use a byte array to separate your binary data

Comment: For your rotations, you may want to consider a different encoding - 0° -> 00, 90° -> 01, 180° -> 11 and 270° -> 10. That way, there's only a single bit difference between angles that are 90° apart.

Comment: Well, i don't get exactly what you want, but i guess you want to compare 2 data integers for a section. What i would do is "extract" the part to compare using a bitwise AND in both ints and then comparing them seems trivial.

Comment: You have the bits backwards with the MSB being on the left and LSB on the right.  You can mask bits 31-26 with 0xFC000000 and bits 25 to 19 with 0x03F00000.  You can shift these bits by using >>26 and masking with 0x3F or >>19 and masking with 0x39   (bits >>25) & 0x3F

Comment: If you just want the new value you could simply xor the old one with the new one and then and the result with the new one. So only the bits which changed are in the result, the other bits are all zeroed out.

Comment: @CShark: When I do ((5 ^ 5) ^ 5) I get 5. If haven't misunderstood you, shouldn't I have gotten 0 because it's unchanged?

Comment: I meant more like ((5 ^ 5) & 5) which indeed is 0, while ((4 ^ 5) & 5) = 1 which is exactly what changed.

Comment: I see! I misread your last comment. :-)

Answer (score 1):

I am not exactly sure what you wanted, but it is certainly possible to compute the modular difference for all fields, using typical [SWAR techniques](https://chessprogramming.wikispaces.com/SIMD+and+SWAR+Techniques):

```
z = ((x | H) - (y &~H)) ^ ((x ^~y) & H)
```

This is the general formula for SWAP subtraction. For 2-bit fields, `H = 0xAAAAAAAA`.

Since there are only two bits and SWAR usually treats the top bit differently (to prevent leaking into the next field), the bits are effectively totally separate.

---

With the new requirements it is also not necessary to do ugly splitting of the fields, for example: (not tested)

```
m = x ^ y;
m = (m | (m >> 1)) & 0x55555555;
m *= 3;
z = y & m; // maybe
```

The idea here is that a xor will produce a 1 somewhere in a field iff it has changed, then OR all bits of the field and put it in the lowest bit of the field, the multiplication by 3 broadcasts it to all bits of the field. & with the new value to get changed fields and zeroes elsewhere, but that means you cannot distinguish between "changed to 0" and "unchanged". Using `m` you can still distinguish them.

Comment: Thanks for the tips on SWAR techniques. I'll have a look at it. I don't quite understand the steps your doing in the second part of your answer, but judging from a few tests, it seems like it's working.

Comment: I've done more testing and get some strange results. I see from your answer that you haven't tested it, which is fine. When x=2 and y=6, I get 4 as the result. When x=7 and y=6, I get 2.

Comment: @ThomasViktil but that's fine, right? eg for x=7, y=6, there is one field that changed namely the lowest one, which changed from 3 to 2, the new value of that field is kept and the other fields are zeroed

Comment: Of course, you're right! When comparing bit by bit, your method works.

Answer (score 0):

Let's see if something like this helps you:

```
int data1 = Convert.ToInt32("00000000000000000000000000011100", 2); //sample data
int data2 = Convert.ToInt32("00000000000000000000000000101000", 2);
int xrotationposition = 26; //start positions of data
int yrotationposition = 28;

string xrotationmask = new string('0', xrotationposition) + "11" + 
                   new string('0',30 - xrotationposition); //mask to extract the data
string yrotationmask = new string('0', yrotationposition) + "11" + 
                   new string('0', 30 - yrotationposition);

int xrotation1 = data1 & Convert.ToInt32(xrotationmask, 2); //bit AND
int xrotation2 = data2 & Convert.ToInt32(xrotationmask, 2);

int yrotation1 = data1 & Convert.ToInt32(yrotationmask, 2);
int yrotation2 = data2 & Convert.ToInt32(yrotationmask, 2);

xrotation1 = (xrotation1 >> 30 - xrotationposition); //shift the bits 
                                                     to the lowest part of byte
xrotation2 = (xrotation2 >> 30 - xrotationposition);

yrotation1 = (yrotation1 >> 30 - yrotationposition);
yrotation2 = (yrotation2 >> 30 - yrotationposition);
```

At the end of this execution, you'll get `xrotation1=1`, `xrotation2=2`,`yrotation1=3` and `yrotation2=2`, that seems easy values to compare.

Hope this helps

Comment: I understand what you've done. All though you have provided a solution that works, I was looking for one where the diffing method didn't need to know about the structure of the data. However, your solution gave me ideas for how to solve that part of the challenge. By putting masks and offsets in an array, I could use a foreach to apply the masks with a bitwise AND to the source, and offset the result to get the data. In any case, I need to get back to the drawing board to rething the challenge.